# Converting JSON to PowerShell object and converting PowerShell back to JSON

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I am exporting the JSON from an Azure Resource Group to a JSON file like this:

```
Export-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $SourceResourceGroupName -Path $filename
```

Then I am getting the JSON contents of the file, then applying it to a variable:

```
$SourceJSON = Get-Content $filename -Raw
```

I then want to turn (convert) this into a PowerShell object:

```
$SourceJSONRG = $SourceJSON | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I then have a look at the resources from with the object:

```
$SourceJSONRG.resources
```

But the `storageProfile` section is blank:

[image]

Whereas looking at the JSON (`$SourceJSON`) in comparison, the `storageProfile` is not blank:

[image]

I have tried using the `Format-Custom -Depth` option to go down much deeper:

```
$SourceJSONRG = $SourceJSON | ConvertFrom-Json
$SourceJSONRG = $SourceJSONRG | Format-Custom -Depth 99
```

But this puts in “`class PSCustomObject`” everywhere which I don’t want.

[image]

The ultimate thing I am trying to do here is convert the JSON to a PowerShell object, make changes to it e.g. change the the URI for a disk, then convert back to JSON to use it for deployment to Azure. In other words, converting the JSON to a PowerShell object makes it much easier for me to work with it.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $TargetResourceGroupName -TemplateFile "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Temp\test20692192.json"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is just an issue of stopping displaying nested values but that does not mean that the values are missing.

You can see that with the following example. Given a sample JSON string like the following and converting it to a JSON object results in the same 'missing' values

```
$jsonString = @"
    {
        "root": {
            "nested1": {
                "nested11": {
                    "leaf1": "some value",
                    "leaf2": "some other value"
                }
            },
            "nested2": {
                "nested22": {
                    "leaf1": "some value",
                    "leaf2": "some other value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
"@
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonString
$obj
```

Output:

```
root                 
----                 
@{nested1=; nested2=}
```

---

But when accessing and modifying the actual object's properties and converting it back to a JSON string you will see everything works

```
$obj.root.nested1.nested11.leaf1 = "42"
$jsonString = ConvertTo-Json $obj -Depth 5
Write-Host $jsonString
```

Output:

```
{
    "root":  {
                 "nested1":  {
                                 "nested11":  {
                                                  "leaf1":  "42",
                                                  "leaf2":  "some other value"
                                              }
                             },
                 "nested2":  {
                                 "nested22":  {
                                                  "leaf1":  "some value",
                                                  "leaf2":  "some other value"
                                              }
                             }
             }
}
```