# Get values from object string to store inside of property

Tags: powershell

I read a **string** that looks something like this:

```
{"text":"yellow","bg":"black","border":"yellow","text":"Test"}
```

How do I get each `text`, `bg`, `border` and `text` to store them in respective properties?

Comment: `$answer = ($yourString | ConvertFrom-Json)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting JSON to PowerShell object and converting PowerShell back to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008020/converting-json-to-powershell-object-and-converting-powershell-back-to-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet converts a JavaScript Object Notation
>   (JSON) formatted string to a custom PSCustomObject object that has a
>   property for each field in the JSON string.
>   -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7

```
$string = '{"text":"yellow","bg":"black","border":"yellow","text":"Test"}'
$StringArray = ($string | ConvertFrom-JSON)
$StringArray
```

Your one problem with the above cmdlet is that you have two objects of the 'text' type. You would just need to modify the above so you can keep both.

You could parse it out with .split() and -replace also.

```
$string = '{"text":"yellow","bg":"black","border":"yellow","text":"Test"}'
$StringArray = $string.split(',')

$StringArray = $StringArray `
    -replace('{','') `
    -replace('}','') `
    -replace('"','')

$StringArray
```